# How to organize service classes in the application

Tags: java, oop

I am building an application where i want to use stripe  apis and mongodb as my database .I am thinking to have a separate service class for calling stripe apis . So my question is ,how should I make those methods `static` or `singleton` or completely `oop` (creating a new object for very request ) ,Stripe internally uses `static` methods to do the process
.How should I have my mongodb service should be static or singleton or oop ,Please suggest your views or any reference you can suggest.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest using frameworks such as Spring, etc

Answer (score 0):

As someone said above, if you're using Spring ( consider Spring Boot) you can use its default mechanism for creating a backend application.

- For example for classes that will map the endpoints you'll use
  `@RestController`
- For your services you'll use `@Service`  For your
  entities that will map the structure from/to mongoDB -> `@Document`
- For repositories you'll use `@Repository`

By default, spring will create these using singleton pattern if not mentioned otherwise.